# How to store multidimensional subscript as variable in R

Tags: r, matrix, multidimensional-array, slice

Suppose I have a matrix,

```
mat <- matrix((1:9)^2, 3, 3)
```

I can slice the matrix like so

```
> mat[2:3, 2]
[1] 25 36
```

**How does one store the subscript as a variable?**  That is, what should `my_sub` be, such that

```
> mat[my_sub]
[1] 25 36
```

A `list` gets "invalid subscript type" error. A vector will lose the multidimensionality.  Seems like such a basic operation to not have a primitive type that fits this usage.

I know I can access the matrix via vector addressing, which means converting from `[2:3, 2]` to `c(5, 6)`, but that mapping presumes knowledge of matrix shape.  What if I simply want `[2:3, 2]` for any matrix shape (assuming it is at least those dimensions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some alternatives.  They both generalize to higher dimenional arrays.

**1) matrix subscripting** If the indexes are all scalar except possibly one, as in the question, then:

```
mi <- cbind(2:3, 2)
mat[mi]

# test
identical(mat[mi],   mat[2:3, 2])
## [1] TRUE
```

In higher dimensions:

```
a <- array(1:24, 2:4)
mi <- cbind(2, 2:3, 3)
a[mi]

# test
identical(a[mi],   a[2, 2:3, 3])
## [1] TRUE
```

It would be possible to extend this to eliminate the scalar restriction using:

```
L <- list(2:3, 2:3)
array(mat[as.matrix(do.call(expand.grid, L))], lengths(L))
```

however, in light of (2) which also uses `do.call` but avoids the need for `expand.grid` it seems unnecessarily complex.

**2) do.call**  This approach does not have the scalar limitation.  `mat` and `a` are from above:

```
L2 <- list(2:3, 1:2)
do.call("[", c(list(mat), L2))

# test
identical(do.call("[", c(list(mat), L2)),   mat[2:3, 1:2])
## [1] TRUE


L3 <- list(2, 2:3, 3:4)
do.call("[", c(list(a), L3))

# test
identical(do.call("[", c(list(a), L3)),   a[2, 2:3, 3:4])
## [1] TRUE
```

This could be made prettier by defining:

```
`%[%` <- function(x, indexList) do.call("[", c(list(x), indexList))
mat %[% list(2:3, 1:2)
a %[% list(2, 2:3, 3:4)
```

Comment: Nice, but isn't `c(list(mat), list(2:3, 1:2))` just `list(mat, 2:3, 1:2)`?

Comment: yes, but the assumptoin is that the second list is the input so they have to be put together.

Comment: Great! You've answered my central question, which is, `my_sub` can be a matrix. You can further generalize approach **(1)** to handle the cases you gave in **(2)** using: 
`data.matrix(expand.grid(2, 2:3, 3:4))`. 
The only drawback is that it loses structure.  Might be worth adding to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `which` argument `arr.ind = TRUE`.

```
x <- c(25, 36)
inx <- which(mat == x, arr.ind = TRUE)
Warning message:
In mat == x :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

mat[inx]
#[1] 25 36
```

Comment: Looking for something matrix agnsotic, i.e.,  no a priori knowledge of values or shape.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question. The `subset` function can actually help. You cannot subset directly your matrix using a vector or a list, but you can store the indexes in a list and use `subset` to do the trick.

```
mat <- matrix(1:12, nrow=4)
mat[2:3, 1:2]
# example using subset
subset(mat, subset = 1:nrow(mat) %in% 2:3, select = 1:2)

# double check
identical(mat[2:3, 1:2], 
          subset(mat, subset = 1:nrow(mat) %in% 2:3, select = 1:2))

# TRUE
```

Actually, we can write a custom function if we want to store the row- and column- indexes in the same list.

```
cust.subset <- function(mat, dim.list){
  subset(mat, subset = 1:nrow(mat) %in% dim.list[[1]], select = dim.list[[2]])
}

# initialize a list that includes your sub-setting indexes
sbdim <- list(2:3, 1:2)
sbdim
# [[1]]
# [1] 2 3

# [[2]]
# [1] 1 2

# subset using your custom f(x) and your list
cust.subset(mat, sbdim)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    2    6
# [2,]    3    7
```

Comment: Was looking for something I can set `my_sub` equal to, rather than a custom accessor function. But still useful to know.